# Implement AMP using ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, amp-html, google-amp

Where to write server side network calls for fetching data and what all lifecycle methods of ReactJs are used?

Note: As in ReactJS, files are made using .js extension and needs many ReactJS imports (like import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react'

So do amp allow these imports as everything is js.

Comment: Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367687/google-amp-with-react)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of people who use React server-side rendering to render AMP pages. Here is a post by Reddit's web team about how they did it https://redditblog.com/2016/09/20/amp-and-reactredux/