# AMP page with CRA

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, amp-html

Is there an easy way of using create-react-app to create a **static** AMP Landing Page? They can easily be created with NextJS. The issue is that our current website is already built with CRA and migrating to NextJS would be difficult.

There are some outdated resources available (e.g. [Google AMP with React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367687/google-amp-with-react)), but they do not take into account current developments, both in regard with CRA and AMP (such as [amp-script](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-script/)).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, CAR is client-side-rendering by default e.g. javascript run and render pages. On the AMP page we can't add react or any regular custom javascript so we can't render the page on the client-side with react.
The alternative solution is next.js, next.js can export AMP pages with react. (SSG or SSR)